# Numpy memory growth while using conditionals

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I am seeing a high memory growth while using broadcast operations:

```py
import numpy as np

nrows = 9000000
ncols = 4
data = np.random.rand(nrows, ncols)

x_min = np.random.rand(nrows)
x_max = np.random.rand(nrows)

#Create Boolean arrays for the bbox subselection (this is where the out of bound memory happens
x_cond = (data[:, 0, np.newaxis] >= x_min) & (data[:, 0, np.newaxis] <= x_max)

# similarly some y_cond
# and some z_cond

conditions = x_cond & y_cond & z_cond

subsel_block = np.where(conditions, data[:, 3, np.newaxis], np.nan)
```

x_min and x_max is always the shape of data.shape[0] and is dynamically calculated on the value of 1st column so I am hiding that implementation for simplicity sake.

Comment: `data[:, 0, np.newaxis] >= x_min` will compare every element in `data[:, 0]` with every element in `x_min`, creating a 9000000x9000000 element array, which is a huge array.

Comment: essentially what I a trying to do here for a row `i` in data array, try to find the rows. in data array that fall within the limits of x_min[i] and x_max[i]. if i do a for loop to do this operation over the rows of such a large array then it takes a LOT of time.

Comment: Unless you have some structure to the data that you can exploit, then I don't know of any way to do this efficiently. As is, you cannot get around the fact that you'll need to compare all 9000000 elements in `data[:,0]` with all 9000000 elements of `x_min`.

Comment: @jared more on the structural information. data is a 4 column array where first three columns are the x, y, z position of a point and the last column holds the value of scalar at that point. x_min and x_max (along with y_min y_max and z_min z_max) forms a bounding box around a point. Critical piece is that for each point the x_min and x_max value for it will be different.

Comment: @jared another idea in my mind is whether chunking (or splitting the data array) might help or not?

Comment: Your code seems inconsistent with what you're saying you want. (1) It sounds like each row in `data[:,0]` needs to be compared with the corresponding row in `x_min` and `x_max`. You're comparing every row with every other row. (2) `x_min` and `x_max` are not the same size when it sounds like they should be. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254009/discussion-between-datapanda-and-jared).