# Fast range query over a million size nD space to determine statistics

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-structures, tree

I have a numpy array with 10 million entries. The array has 5 columns, where the first 4 columns specify the co-ordinates of x, y, z and t. The last column specifies a scalar value at each of these points. Now for every point in this dataset I want to query for points within an n-D bounding box specified by some x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max, z_min, z_max, t_min and t_max. For the points within the bounding box, calculate the median and standard deviation of the values and store it.

Few things to note:

1. the bounding box specification for each point will be different, for
   some it might be a small box for some points it might be larger box.
2. note that the x, y, z, t; all 4 axis have different resolutions and
   different scales.
3. The array is an ordered array along the first axis but not the other three axis.

Right now, I have leveraged the info of point number 3 to reduce my search space but I would like to maybe create some sort of Tree data structure which at once fetch me the points within the bounding box, because I need to do this query 10 million times for each row (think about a marching bounding box centered around each point).

With the above information, I have tried to implement the following pseudocode

```py
import numpy as np
import time

num_points = 10_000_000
df_us = np.random.rand(num_points, 5)
df = df_us[df_us[:,0].argsort()] #sort along the first axis to mimick the real data feature

# for this expt ignoring the fact that each axis has different limits and different sampling resolution
xmin = np.random.rand(num_points)
xmax = xmin + 0.2
ymin = np.random.rand(num_points)
ymax = ymin + 0.4
zmin = np.random.rand(num_points)
zmax = zmin + 0.4
tmin = np.random.rand(num_points)
tmax = tmin + 0.4

def bbox_stat(xr_df, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, zmax, tmin, tmax):
    for i in range(len(xmin)):
        # use the fact the first axis is presorted in the dataset
        x_si = np.searchsorted(xr_df[:,0], xmin[i], side='left')
        x_ei = np.searchsorted(xr_df[:,0], xmax[i], side='right')
        
        y_conditions = (xr_df[x_si:x_ei, 1] >= ymin[i]) & (xr_df[x_si:x_ei, 1] <= ymax[i])
        z_conditions = (xr_df[x_si:x_ei, 2] >= zmin[i]) & (xr_df[x_si:x_ei, 2] <= zmax[i])
        t_conditions = (xr_df[x_si:x_ei, 3] >= tmin[i]) & (xr_df[x_si:x_ei, 3] <= tmax[i])
        conditions = y_conditions & z_conditions & t_conditions
        med_i = xr_df[x_si:x_ei,:][conditions,3].median() # use this fillup an array mean
        std_i = xr_df[x_si:x_ei,:][conditions,3].std() # use this to fillup an array std


arguments = []
num_cores = 50
orig_len = df.shape[0]
unit_len = orig_len//num_cores
for i in range(num_cores):
   arguments.append((df, xmin[i*uni_len:(i+1)*uni_len], xmax[i*uni_len:(i+1)*uni_len], ymin[i*uni_len:(i+1)*uni_len], ymax[i*uni_len:(i+1)*uni_len], zmin[i*uni_len:(i+1)*uni_len], zmax[i*uni_len:(i+1)*uni_len], tmin[i*uni_len:(i+1)*uni_len], tmax[i*uni_len:(i+1)*uni_len]))

start_time = time.time()
pool = Pool(processes=num_cores)
pool.starmap(bbox_stat, arguments)
pool. Close()
pool. Join()
end_time = time.time()

print(f"Time taken: {end_time - start_time} seconds")
```

Comment: A kd-tree can be useful here assuming the bounding boxes are small (compared to the overall dataset). Otherwise, the algorithm is certainly good. That being said micro-optimisations are certainly possible. Another approach is to use a GPU in this case though this is far from being easy here and the median, which is generally not very efficiently computed on GPUs, will be certainly the bottleneck.

Comment: Did you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_searching#Orthogonal_range_searching already?

Comment: @JérômeRichard I want to try the kdtree working but can’t get it. The scipy implementation of kdtree has only a ball search whereas I need a bounding box or range search. Also there is the fact that all axes have their different resolution and scales.

Comment: @jbapple yes I did read it. I am also thinking on the cost of creating a data structure. Given that I need to query a 10 million ranges over the dataset, I think it might pay off.

Comment: SciPy has a KDTree but it does not provide a method fitting with your needs indeed. Doing 1 request at a time is not a problem. I am not sure there is a fast existing module for that. If not, you will need to reimplement one yourself (still assuming the boxes are small enough). I am not sur Python is a good langage for this task either. Creating many temporary Numpy arrays is suboptimal and using multiple processes too (though the overhead should not be huge here).

Answer (score 1):

### Updated Solution

My original solution (kept below for posterity) was incorrect due to a misunderstanding on my part. That said, this problem still suffers from efficiency issues (due to its size), though hopefully, my answer will be a good starting point. Similar to my original solution, you can use a kd tree to speed up the search. Using the scipy [`KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html), you can create a kd tree for each direction (x, y, z) and t and then use the [`query_ball_point`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point) to find points that are within a given distance (defined by `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`,...) from the center of the cuboid. Using the intersection of the points found using each range finds only the points that satisfy all the conditions.

```py
import numpy as np
from time import perf_counter
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

num_points = 10_000

rng = np.random.default_rng(1245)
df_us = rng.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(num_points, 5))

# sort along the first axis to mimick the real data feature
df = df_us[df_us[:, 0].argsort()]

tic = perf_counter()
xtree = KDTree(df[:, 0, None])
ytree = KDTree(df[:, 1, None])
ztree = KDTree(df[:, 2, None])
ttree = KDTree(df[:, 3, None])
toc = perf_counter()
print(f"Tree creation time: {toc - tic:.4f}")

# for this expt ignoring the fact that each axis has different limits and
# different sampling resolution
xmins = rng.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(num_points,))
xmaxs = xmins + 0.2
ymins = rng.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(num_points,))
ymaxs = ymins + 0.4
zmins = rng.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(num_points,))
zmaxs = zmins + 0.4
tmins = rng.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(num_points,))
tmaxs = tmins + 0.4


def bbox_stat(df, trees, x_range, y_range, z_range, t_range):
    xtree, ytree, ztree, ttree = trees
    xmin, xmax = x_range
    ymin, ymax = y_range
    zmin, zmax = z_range
    tmin, tmax = t_range

    cuboid_coord = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])

    x_half_length = (xmax - xmin)/2
    cuboid_coord[0] = xmin + x_half_length

    y_half_length = (ymax - ymin)/2
    cuboid_coord[1] = ymin + y_half_length

    z_half_length = (zmax - zmin)/2
    cuboid_coord[2] = zmin + z_half_length

    t_half_length = (tmax - tmin)/2
    cuboid_coord[3] = tmin + t_half_length

    xpoints_idxs = set(xtree.query_ball_point(cuboid_coord[0], x_half_length))
    ypoints_idxs = set(ytree.query_ball_point(cuboid_coord[1], y_half_length))
    zpoints_idxs = set(ztree.query_ball_point(cuboid_coord[2], z_half_length))
    tpoints_idxs = set(ttree.query_ball_point(cuboid_coord[3], t_half_length))

    points_idxs = xpoints_idxs & ypoints_idxs & zpoints_idxs & tpoints_idxs
    points_idxs = np.array(list(points_idxs))

    # about 2x slower
    # xpoints_idxs = np.array(xtree.query_ball_point(cuboid_coord[0],
    #                                                x_half_length))
    # ypoints_idxs = np.array(ytree.query_ball_point(cuboid_coord[1],
    #                                                y_half_length))
    # zpoints_idxs = np.array(ztree.query_ball_point(cuboid_coord[2],
    #                                                z_half_length))
    # tpoints_idxs = np.array(ttree.query_ball_point(cuboid_coord[3],
    #                                                t_half_length))

    # points_idxs = xpoints_idxs
    # points_idxs = np.intersect1d(points_idxs, ypoints_idxs, assume_unique=True)
    # points_idxs = np.intersect1d(points_idxs, zpoints_idxs, assume_unique=True)
    # points_idxs = np.intersect1d(points_idxs, tpoints_idxs, assume_unique=True)

    if points_idxs.size == 0:
        return -1, -1
    vals_within = df[points_idxs, -1]
    return np.median(vals_within), vals_within.std()


trees = (xtree, ytree, ztree, ttree)
x_ranges = np.vstack((xmins, xmaxs)).T
y_ranges = np.vstack((ymins, ymaxs)).T
z_ranges = np.vstack((zmins, zmaxs)).T
t_ranges = np.vstack((tmins, tmaxs)).T

median = np.full((df.shape[0], 1), -1.)
std = np.full((df.shape[0], 1), -1.)

tic = perf_counter()
for i, ranges in enumerate(zip(x_ranges, y_ranges, z_ranges, t_ranges)):
    res = bbox_stat(df, trees, *ranges)
    median[i], std[i] = res
toc = perf_counter()
print(f"bbox_stat time: {toc - tic:.4f}")
```

I've only been able to run this in serial up to 100,000 points, which took 12 minutes on my machine. 10 million may be intractable (at least in serial).

The current issue with this code is that the kd tree becomes slower and slower to query as the number of points increases, and this is done for 4 trees. For now, I will leave this solution as a starting point and maybe I or someone else will improve it.

---

### Old (Incorrect) Solution

The issue with this problem, which I mentioned in your [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76436971/numpy-memory-growth-while-using-conditionals), is that you cannot feasibly store all the information you want. In the end, you want the median and standard deviation of the points within any cuboid around a point of interest. Assuming the median and std values were 1 byte, you would have 10,000,000 x 10,000,000 datapoints, corresponding to 100Tb arrays, each. And that is assuming the values are booleans, when they are, in fact, floats (assuming the smallest `np.float16`, which are 2 bytes, that's 200Tb for each array).

Assuming you have a smaller, more manageable problem, you can use a kd tree to speed up the search. Using the scipy [`KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html), you can use the [`query_ball_point`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query_ball_point) method with `p=np.inf` to query a cube region. This can be used to quickly downsample the number of points you have to check by first querying the largest possible cube. With that result, you can go ahead with your normal checks and from there compute the median and standard deviations.

```py
import numpy as np
from time import perf_counter
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

num_points = 100

rng = np.random.default_rng()
df_us = rng.uniform(size=(num_points, 5))
# sort along the first axis to mimick the real data feature
df = df_us[df_us[:, 0].argsort()]

# KDTree of the points
tree = KDTree(df[:, :3])

# for this example, ignoring the fact that each axis has different limits and different sampling resolution
xmin = rng.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(num_points,))
xmax = xmin + 0.2
ymin = rng.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(num_points,))
ymax = ymin + 0.4
zmin = rng.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(num_points,))
zmax = zmin + 0.4
tmin = rng.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(num_points,))
tmax = tmin + 0.4

# you used 0.2 and 0.4 above, but I'm assuming that isn't standard
x_range = xmax - xmin
x_range_max = x_range.max()
y_range = ymax - ymin
y_range_max = y_range.max()
z_range = zmax - zmin
z_range_max = z_range.max()
range_max = max([x_range_max, y_range_max, z_range_max])

def bbox_stat(point, df, tree, range_max, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, zmax, tmin, tmax):
    points_idxs = np.array(tree.query_ball_point(point, range_max, p=np.inf))
    points = df[points_idxs]
    x_cond = (points[:, 0, None] >= xmin) & (points[:, 0, None] <= xmax)
    y_cond = (points[:, 1, None] >= ymin) & (points[:, 1, None] <= ymax)
    z_cond = (points[:, 2, None] >= zmin) & (points[:, 2, None] <= zmax)
    t_cond = (points[:, 3, None] >= tmin) & (points[:, 3, None] <= tmax)
    cond = x_cond & y_cond & z_cond & t_cond

    median = np.full((df.shape[0], 1), -1.)
    std = np.full((df.shape[0], 1), -1.)
    for idx, col in enumerate(cond.T):
        if np.any(col):
            val_within = df[points_idxs[col],-1]
            median[idx] = np.median(val_within)
            std[idx] = val_within.std()

    return median, std

# example with the point at index 12
median, std = bbox_stat(df[12, :3], df, tree, range_max, 
                        xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, zmax, tmin, tmax)

tic = perf_counter()
for i in range(num_points):
    bbox_stat(df[i, :3], df, tree, range_max, 
                            xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, zmax, tmin, tmax)
toc = perf_counter()
print(f"Time: {toc - tic:.4f}")
```

Now, this might actually run for 10,000,000 points depending on how the points are actually spaced. You showed using a random distribution of points from 0 to 1, which means with 10,000,000 points, there will still be a very large number of points in a given cuboid. If the points are more spread out, the tree query will return fewer points (hopefully, significantly fewer). But you will still have an issue with storing the information. But if the data is spread out enough, you will have sparse median and std matrices, so you can use `scipy.sparse` to reduce the storage requirements.

Comment: there are few issues with this approach that is not applicable to the problem at hand. First and foremost is the way range_max is being determine. Each axis has different scales so the max_valu - min_value is not going to be applicable for comparison `max([x_range_max, y_range_max, z_range_max])`. Also I am just interested in getting median value of the bounding box for points specified by row i and so on. So median and std deviation will be just vectors of length df.shape[0]. I have already reduced the comparisons by leveraging the fact that first dimension is sorted.

Comment: You have 10,000,000 bounding cuboids that you want to test. What I did was find the smallest cube that all the cuboids could fit in. With that, I query the tree to quickly find all the points that could possibly be within range, so the condition checking is much faster. Regarding the median and std vectors, that is what my function does, it returns a vector of shape 10,000,000 x 1. The issue is that you will have to compute that for every point, meaning you'll have 10,000,000 of those vectors.

Comment: I just updated the code for a mistake I had with not transposing `cond` before looping through it. I should have been selecting the columns as I intended, not the rows.

Comment: I think this will not work because your bounding box as it marches from one corner of the supercube to the other corner of the supercube it should essentially be seeing most of the points in this dataset. also my biggest concern is around the scale of range_max. in the x direction the numbers are in 4 digits and the increment is in 2 digits. in the y direction the numbers are in the range (0,1) with increment in decimals, smallest being in the range of 1e-2. the max argument will ignore the range on the axis that might look very small on an absolute sense (ref. point 2 in my question)

Comment: Have you actually tested the code to see if it produces the wrong results?

Comment: And I don't see why the scale is an issue. If you are checking for points within a 100 units wide by 20 units tall by 1 unit deep, the code will find points within a 100 unit cubed area, which the actual points will fall within. But now you don't need to look through 10,000,000 points, only the points that fall within the 100 unit cubed region.

Comment: yes, i did try to query a few points using the kdtree call in a small experiment. it's not functioning as intended and that's the reason why I don't this will work as intended.

Comment: Have you tried the most recent version that I updated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254028/discussion-between-datapanda-and-jared).